# Using FFI (gem) or similar in Rubymotion

Tags: rubygems, rubymotion

I have a external C-Library I want to use for my Rubymotion (Redpotion) project.
I have used the Library for a Ruby project and used the gem `FFI`, which worked great.

However I can't get this gem to work in Rubymotion (properly because it is not a Rubymotion gem).
I get this error.

`uninitialized constant Libdedx::FFI (NameError)`

The gem is included in the `Gemfile` and code is below

```
module test
    class Dedx_workspace < FFI::Struct
        layout  :loaded_data, :pointer,
                :datasets, :int,
                :active_datasets, :int
    end
end
```

Does anybody know if this is possible or know another way of using an external C-library?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use FFI. However, there's another great way to use C libraries.

Just wrap your C functions in an Objective-C class and statically link it in.

```
@interface MyWrapper : NSObject
- (void)someMethod;
@end


@implementation MyWrapper

- (void) someMethod
{
    // C stuff here
}

@end
```

In your Rakefile

```
app.vendor_project('vendor/MyWrapper', :static)
```

Comment: Would you be able to make an example for my case, because I'm not sure how to do this and have no experience. [link to library](http://sourceforge.net/p/libdedx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/libdedx/), here exist the file **dedx.c** which have a method called `dedx_get_program_list`. Would you be able to show me how use this method from rubymotion? Or is this somewhat impossible?

Comment: It's certainly not impossible, but I unfortunately don't have time to show you an extensive example. You should be able to link in the dedx.c file and call dedx_get_program_list() inside the // c stuff here method body.